# Highlight the text that precedes a "citation needed" tag

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

On Wikipedia (and MediaWiki in general), is it possible to highlight the text that is preceded by a "citation needed" tag, in order to clarify what the tag specifically refers to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Wikipedia:

Use the {{[Reference necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aReference_necessary)}} template.

It adds a dotted gray underline beneath the text selection of your choice.

Plus it adds a "<sup>[*[citation needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCitation_needed)*]</sup>" inline template at the end.

On other MediaWiki websites, you may have do do it yourself using CSS or something. Let us know how it works out.